# window.location not working in ajax form submission callback

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have forms (register and login) and modal background that gets added to the page if a user clicks the Login button.  I'm submitting the forms via ajax using jquery.

```
$.post("/login",{
    "ajax":true,
    "email":$("#popup-window #login-form-email").val(),
    "password":$("#popup-window #login-form-password").val()
    },function(response){
        console.log(response);

        if(response.message=="success"){
            if(response.user.type==1){
                        console.log(window);

                        // window.location = "http://www.whatever.com/admin";
                        window[0].ownerDocument.location.href="http://www.whatever.com/admin";
                    } 
            if(response.user.type==2) window[0].ownerDocument.location.href = "http://www.whatever.com/trades";
        }else{
                $("#popup-window #login-form").append("<div id='invalid-login'>Invalid Login</div>");
            }

    },"json");
```

---

Everything works except

```
window.location = "http://www.whatever.com/admin";
```

and the window object isn't what I expect.  Looking through it I found that the following does work

```
window[0].ownerDocument.location.href="http://www.whatever.com/admin";
```

in everything I tested (IE7, IE8, IE9, chrome, firefox).  I'm not sure why that is or whether or not this is the correct way to do it.

I'm relatively new to javascript and the DOM and I'd really like to understand what's happening here.

Comment: did you try window.location.href ?

Comment: I did try that.  It's the window object that is strange.  It has no location property.

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.location.href = "http://www.whatever.com/admin";`

Comment: I tried that. Got back `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of undefined`.  And the window object isn't what I was expecting.  It seems to be an array with my "<div id='popup-window'>" as the only element.